# upon including memberExpression inside blockStatement of functionExpression, error memberExpression expected type Identifier, got null,

Tags: babeljs

I'm encountering strange behavior while writing a transpiler where the moment I supply a member expression inside the blockStatement to my functionExpression, it tells me this: 
`TypeError: unknown: Property property of MemberExpression expected node to be of a type ["Identifier"] but instead got null`.

But this is certainly not what was provided to it -- I definitely gave it an identifier:

```
 95             const arguments0 = t.memberExpression(
 96               t.identifier('arguments'),
 97               t.numericLiteral(0),
 98               true
 99             )
100             const callEval = t.callExpression(
101               t.identifier('eval'),
102               // [ arguments0 ]
103               [
104                 t.memberExpression(
105                   t.identifier('arguments'),
106                   t.numericLiteral(0),
107                   true
108                 )
109               ] 
110             ) 
111             const returnCallEval = t.returnStatement(callEval)
112             const captureArg2Block = t.blockStatement([
113               returnCallEval
114             ])
115             const captureArg2 = t.functionExpression(
116               null,
117               [],
118               captureArg2Block
119             )
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the visitor was revisiting this section of the tree. If you are going to add a node and you do not want it to be visited, then you must create a weak set use that to avoid traversing nodes you have created